# Advanced classical electrodynamics book

Tags: electromagnetism

As I have already studied Griffiths, I want something with modern and advanced approach both towards theory and problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical advanced textbook for E&M is [Jackson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047130932X).  I don't know if it is really considered modern, but it is still taught in my graduate program at UC Berkeley.

Comment: But it is not enough, I need something more.